# Trying To Read from Excel File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my .js, I want to be able to provide some function with the path, and then be able to read from the .xlsx file.  I have tried the FileReader(), but there is no way to specify a local path to read from.  Does anyone know of any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN page for FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) links to [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) which has examples.

You specify the local path using a file input:

```
<input type="file" id="input">
```

and then

```
var selected_file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(selected_file);
```

Obviously a web page cannot specify an arbitrary file on the user's system to read. That would be a massive security risk.